# Colocar comando date dentro do e-mail

Tags: variáveis, email, data

Possuo um `script`, e gostaria que o mesmo enviasse um e-mail para os usuários informando o horário que o mesmo fosse executado.

**Exemplo:**

```
$script_deploy.sh
# Envio de e-mail aviso deploy
echo "=> Envio de e-mail para os usuarios sobre o inicio do deploy"
mail -s "DEPLOY" users@dominio.com.br < /opt/email-inicio-deploy.txt

$/opt/email-inicio-deploy.txt
echo "Informamos que o sistema tera um deploy as `date +%H:%M`"
```

**Pois bem, o email chega com o seguinte texto:**

```
Informamos que o sistema tera um deploy as `date +%H:%M`
```

Como faço para o comando `date` ser interpretado?
Já tentei de diversas formas e não consegui.

Comment: Pode indicar as formas que já tentou?

Answer (score 1):

Olá,

Você consegue enviar a mensagem com a hora da seguinte forma:

```
mail -s "DEPLOY" users@dominio.com.br <<< "Informamos que o sistema tera um deploy as $(date +'%H:%M')"
```

Comment: Obrigado, pela resposta, mas pela linha do shell eu consigo. O que preciso é que ele interprete de dentro de um arquivo, creio que seria necessario um sub-shell 

-> Enviando pela linha de comando direto sai assim:
mail -s "DEPLOY" amachado@fapesp.br <<< "Informamos que o sistema tera um deploy as $(date +'%H:%M')"

-> mensagem recebida pelo cliente 
Informamos que o sistema tera um deploy as 14:59

-> enviando via arquivo, a mensagem chega da forma abaixo:

echo "Informamos que o sistema tera um deploy as $(date +'%H:%M')"